# Return in textbox correct dataformat date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have datepicker from jQuery. In textbox return me this dataformat:  Sat Aug 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200. I want to return "dd.mm.yy". 
`dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"` doesn't work.
How can I do?. `$(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val(d);` doesn't work too.

Here is code:

```
$(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                showWeek: true,
                firstDay: 6,
                autosize: true, 

                onSelect: function (date) {
                    var d = new Date(date);
                    var index = d.getDay();
                    if (index == 0) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
                    }
                    else if (index == 1) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 2);
                    }
                    else if (index == 2) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);
                    }
                    else if (index == 3) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 4);
                    }
                    else if (index == 4) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 5);
                    }
                    else if (index == 5) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 6);
                    }
                    else if (index == 6) {
                        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 0);
                    }
                    $(this).val(d);  

                },
            });
        });
```

Comment: Where did you put the `dateFormat`? It is an option you can add and it works with that format (dd.mm.yy) too.

Comment: @putvande I put `dateFormat` under `autosize:true,` Work but in textbox write: Invalid Date.

Comment: You might need to check / remove what you have in your `onSelect`. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: In onselect select date, and return first day on week(saturday).  It's work, but not currect format.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to select the first day of the week (saturday) and put it in the input box?

Comment: Yes. But not this format: `Sat Aug 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200` but this `'dd-mm-yy'`